# localStorage not working in other host - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon

I am developing a firefox addon. i use localStorage to save some data and retrieve.
function to check if it is available or not

```
if(!localStorage.getItem('font')) {
  populateStorage();
}else{
  var aValue = localStorage.getItem('font');
  alert(aValue);
```

if not then create

```
function populateStorage(){
  localStorage.setItem('cname', name);
  localStorage.setItem('font', 'Helvetica');
  localStorage.setItem('image', 'myCat.png');
}
```

This is perfectly working localhost but if i visit other host like google.com and try to get i am getting error not found

```
if(!localStorage.getItem('font')) {
 alert('Not found !!!!');
}else{
 var aValue = localStorage.getItem('font');
 alert(aValue);
}
```

is there any way to fix this issue ? or am i doing it in wrong way ?

Answer (score 2):

LocalStorage is **intended** to be accessible only from the same host. This allows different websites to have a different scope for their data, and also ensures that one website cannot access data from another website.

From MDN,

> The read-only localStorage property allows you to access a **Storage object for the Document's origin**; the stored data is saved across browser sessions.

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

---

If you need to share data across different domains, you should use server-side persistence.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've undestood local storage is not cross domain solution, so this behavior is correct.
What you need to do is fallow MDN solution. I've found something like this:

```
// define 2 objects
var monster = {
  name: "Kraken",
  tentacles: true,
  eyeCount: 10
}

var kitten = {
  name: "Moggy",
  tentacles: false,
  eyeCount: 2
}

// store the objects
browser.storage.local.set({kitten, monster})
  .then(setItem, onError);
```

(code copied from MDN > JavaScript APIs > storage )

In this solution data will be pinned to browser/extension, not to domain. But be aware, that data still will be destroyed when user clear browser cache or something like that.